# Calling a library function by offset or index

Tags: java, android, c, shared-libraries

I am writing an android and need to call a function from a 3rd party shared library (.so) file, but receive an error stating that the named method isn't found.

The library is being loaded by the app, but for whatever reason, using the name of the function refuses to work.

Is there any way for me to call the function by via an index number or the relative offset using the android SDK or C?

Or maybe, is there some way that I can use the android sdk to find the memory location of the library, add the offset, and then call the function based on the resulting address?

Comment: hv marked that lib code as lib in android?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I have added it to my Android.mk file and added the and 'static native ...' entry in the java code.  I know the library is being loaded (at leasts in some capacity) because my error before this was 'findLibrary returned null', I assumed that was fixed based on the fact that error went away and i got a new one :)

Comment: Are you trying to access it from C or Java?  You can't reference by index from Java.  I wouldn't suggest it from C either-  its a fragile thing to do, if you ever update the library you'll crash all over the place.

Comment: I am trying to do it from Java but C could work.  Also, updating the library is not a concern.